# Exception handling while parsing JSONObjects

Tags: java, json

I am parsing a large `JSONArray` (33000 items approximately) of JSON objects. I am converting the JSON objects into my own objects in my app. It looks a  bit like the following:

```
Card card = Card.build(cardObj.getString("name"))
                .setFoo(cardObj.getString("foo"))
                .setBar(cardObj.getInt("bar"))
                .setBaz(cardObj.getString("baz"))
                ... about 10 more
```

**The Problem** is that all of the cards (in the raw JSON) do not have the same keys. Because of this, I would have to have a try catch block for every single line of code in my parser, because any exception would have to be handled before the code can continue executing. For example, as in the snippet above, if I were parsing an object that didn't have `bar`, then the code will immediately jump to the exception handling, skipping the step where it sets the `baz` value.

**My Question**: Is there a way of doing this where I can avoid try-catching every single line? I know that you can't *ignore* exceptions, but perhaps there is something similar that may help.

**A Better Example**

```
try {
    Card card = Card.build(cardObj.getString("name"))
                    .setFoo(cardObj.getString("foo"))
                    .setBar(cardObj.getInt("bar"))
                    .setBaz(cardObj.getString("baz"))
} catch (JSONException e) {
    // The code will jump here for any exception. 
}
```

If the code fails while setting `foo` or `bar`, the execution context will jump to the error handling step inside of the catch block. The function calls following the offending line **will never run**, therefore `bar` or `baz` may never be set, even if they exist in the original JSON. I can see no way to prevent this other than try-catching every single line or by checking to make sure every single value exists beforehand. Is there no better way of doing this?

Comment: So you can't just put a try-catch block around the whole thing? Or use the `throws` keyword?

Comment: No, because the executing context will simply 'skip' the rest of the lines and jump straight to handling the exception.

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your JSON library has a way of handling *default values* I **strongly** suggest to use it and pass `null` or whatever is good-enough as default value.

The method might look something like `jsonObject.getString(String key, String defaultValue)`.

---

But if your JSON library does not provide you with way to use **default values** you can wrap each `getXXX()` call in method which takes care about handling exceptions like this:

```
String getOrDefault(JSONObject obj, String key, String defValue) {
     try {
         String value = obj.getString(key);
         return value;
     }
     catch (Exception ex) {
         return defValue;
     }
}

// similary create functions for all data types.
```

And then at builder part use:

```
Card card = Card.build(getOrDefault(cardObj, "name", null))
                    ... about 10 more
```

Comment: Ahhh very clever. Ill definitely try it if no one can think of a better way other than 'use library x and your problems disappear'

Comment: @Campbell I also mentioned the way of using default value method overload. Many JSON libraries I worked with **had** this feature.

Comment: @Campbell This is the overload you are looking for if you are using `javax.json.JsonObject` https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonObject.html#getString-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-

Comment: Yes that's perfect, I don't know why I didn't look at the docs beforehand. Ill accept your post as the answer. Thanks for replying so quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Just check if your `JSONObject` contains object (of correct type) before you do `getSomething`.  `JSONObject` implements Map - https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonObject.html

Also, `JsonArray` implements `List<JsonValue>` https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonArray.html

For example, before calling `cardObj.getString("foo")` call `cardObj.containsKey("foo")`. Then you may consider checking value type:

```
JsonValue value=cardObj.get("foo");
if (value.getValueType()=!JsonValue.ValueType.STRING) {
 //do something reasonable for invalid type. 
}
```

You may consider using library working at higher level of abstraction. Working with [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson), it will do nothing for non-existing json tags (matching fields in `Card` object will remain null).

When using Jackson, deserializing is matter of calling

```
Card card=new ObjectMapper().readValue("jsonString",Card.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not exactly the solution to your problem, but anyway why are you bothering so much about parsing the JSON by writing hundred lines of codes when there are some beautiful libraries like [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson)?

Its pretty easy to use this library and all you have to do is writing a POJO class in which your JSON will be parsed into.

And yes, if some JSON key is not present in your JSON schema, you don't have to worry about that too. Gson handles this case too. For example, let me take a POJO class like this.

```
public class Parsed {
    public String name;
    public String foo;
    public Integer bar;
    public String baz;
}
```

So now, if in your JSON, the `foo` key is not available, then it'll assigned to `null` while parsing your JSON with Gson. So from your code just check if the value is null while assigning it to some other variable. That's it.

Comment: I'm using Volley for android. It natively uses JSONObjects and JSONArrays.

Comment: So this is where you can get some help - https://kylewbanks.com/blog/tutorial-parsing-json-on-android-using-gson-and-volley

Answer (score 0):

I see two options here.

1. Validate `cardObj` before creating `Card` which may require lots of boring code to write.
2. Relax `Card` object creation - allow to create it with invalid data and then validate by implementing `getValidationErrors` method which would return collection of errors with details which field failed which reason. JSR303 annotations and validator would fit here as well.